# Fortify error: Code Correctness: Erroneous Class Compare

Tags: java, error-handling, fortify

The method doRequest() determines an object's type based its class name on line 135. This practice can lead to unexpected behavior or allow an attacker to inject a malicious class.

this is my code:

`if(request.getClass().getName().equals(STRING_CONFIG))`

so STRING_CONFIG is definetely a string, and getName() gives me a String to, so what is wrong with this code? Why is that Fortify test telling me that?

Answer (score 3):

> STRING_CONFIG is definetely a string, and getName() gives me a String to, so what is wrong with this code?

Fortify doesn't test for compliance with language constraints -- that's the compiler's job.  Its complaint therefore has nothing to do with whether it makes sense *in general* to compare two `String`s via one's `equals()` method.  It has actually managed to perform a deeper semantic analysis to determine (correctly) that you are attempting to determine the type of an object via its class's name, exactly as the message says.

> Why is that Fortify test telling me that?

Because even a class's fully-qualified name does not uniquely identify it in the universe of possible classes, and not necessarily even in the universe of classes that can be accessed by your application.  Classes are scoped by the `ClassLoader` that loaded them, and therefore there can be more than one with a given fully-qualified name loaded into the same VM at the same time.  There is at least a hypothetical risk that an object of some malicious class of the given name has been injected into your application, and that havoc will ensue if you treat it as an object of a different but same-named class.

Instead of comparing class name `Strings` via `equals()`, compare `Class` objects via `==` or perhaps use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (request.getClass() == my.package.ClassIWasExpecting.class) {
    // ...
} else if (request instanceof my.package.OtherAcceptableClass) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that `instanceof` provides a less specific criterion than the class comparison does.

There is still some potential for malicious classes to be injected, but it would have to occur at a different, harder to reach point that way.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to identify if an object is an instance of a class is to use `instanceof`

Else anyone can create a class (and package) with the same name of your class and fool this piece of code.  Which is what fortify points to here.

If your code is

```
private static final String STRING_CONFIG = "com.abc.Test";
if(request.getClass().getName().equals(STRING_CONFIG))
```

change this piece of code to

```
if(request instanceof com.abc.Test)
```